# Iterating through data and generate pages with PDFKit

Tags: javascript, node.js, pdf-generation, pdfkit

I want to generate pages in pdfkit using a for loop. In my application I created a new module which is loaded on a request (all this works fine and I can create a pdf without a loop). With the loop pdfkit creates a pdf, but this one is broken then.

The code from the module:

```
module.exports = function () {

var Project = require('./models/projects');
var PDFDocument = require('pdfkit');
var doc = new PDFDocument;

doc.fontSize(25);
doc.text('Portfolio');

Project
    .find()
    .exec(function (err, projects) {
      if (err) {
          console.log(err);
      } else {
        projects.forEach(function (project) {

            var project_customer = project.customer;

            doc.addPage();
            doc.text('project_customer');

        });
      }
    });

doc.addPage();
doc.text('project_customer');

doc.save();

    doc.write('./output.pdf');

}
```

Is there an solution how I can get a pdf which is not broken?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code `Project.find().exec(...)` runs asynchronously. Which means you are creating the PDF document and saving before the call to `Project.find().exec(...)` completes.

I suggest moving the PDF code into the callback included in `exec()` like so:

```
module.exports = function () {

    var Project = require('./models/projects');
    var PDFDocument = require('pdfkit');

    Project
      .find()
      .exec(function (err, projects) {
        if (err) return console.log(err);

        var doc = new PDFDocument;
        doc.fontSize(25);
        doc.text('Portfolio');

        projects.forEach(function (project) {

          var project_customer = project.customer;

          doc.addPage();
          doc.text('project_customer');
        });

        doc.addPage();
        doc.text('project_customer');

        doc.save();

        doc.write('./output.pdf');

      });
}
```

Comment: Oh my god, you are right. Thanks, i forgot that the code is running asynchronously. 
Now it works fine.